Returning to the US for 2 weeks after a short stay around 6 months prior with an ESTA but a poor entry interview - worried about visiting again
I am currently making plans to go on a 14 day trip to the US around April or May 2025, my first ever being 11 days back in late August - I may be heavily overthinking this, but I am worried I may be denied entry after my experience the first time around.
On my last trip; I presented my passport, ticket & return ticket, answered all questions honestly - I was meeting a friend who I've known going back 10 years, that the friend is married, my place of casual employment and that I am a sole trader in the IT sector.
I was still pulled aside for further questioning (I partly blame this on my lack of sleep during the flight and overall exhaustion). Aside from the expected questions of national interest & state security, I was given a form to fill which effectively contained all information that was required when applying for my ESTA as well as further details on my family.
While I have absolutely nothing to hide, the experience did leave me slightly shaken, admittedly the CBP agent who interviewed me was quite polite if not stern. Am I at any risk of denial on my next flight in given this event? Is there anything I can do better in future visits? This especially concerns me as I had a wonderful time and would like to visit more often in the future, for equal periods of stay (e.g 10 to 14 days once every 4 months).
I've added some context on myself if it helps

Australian citizen from birth, living in Australia
Mid-eastern ethnicity and legal name
Male
Travelled to Turkey back in 2019 for a 3 week trip to see some family/general tourism
Casually employed + a sole-proprietor
Purpose of visit: spending time with a friend, I would be residing at her location for the duration of my stay - with a budget of at least 2000 USD, likely in an international card as opposed to my bank account. (I was not questioned on this my first time around)
Will be booking a return ticket, with no stops between Australia and the US
No intent of immigration


I think you are overthinking. If they had something, they would tell you (or just deny the previous time). Considering that you speak English well, you should haven't missed such part.

@GiacomoCatenazzi - Thank you for your reply, I sincerely apologize but can you please clarify what you mean by "Missed such part"?

After they asked the questions and required you to fill the form, what was the outcome? Stamp + "Thank you, welcome to the United States"? Or did they give you a limited time (less than 6 months), or give you a warning about something? If the latter, then they probably said something specific you need to pay attention to. If the former, then as long as you stick to what you wrote here, there's no reason for any worry. You were "profiled" to be a potential problem, they checked, they did not find any actual issue, they let you in. Will they do it again? Who knows...

Unfortunately US immigration officers have a fair amount of "discretion" and much less of a defined process or oversight than most other countries do. So you'll never know what exactly you will get. Your case looks fine to me and I don't think there is anything to worry about. Its possible the officers were bored, had a slow day and just generally enjoy making other people miserable. While some CPB officers act professional, many others do not and I have seen them doing blatantly illegal stuff in secondary. They can get away with pretty much anything since there you have no recourse.

@BH: I was referring about they would tell you. For people speaking other languages, they may miss the real meaning of some (maybe informal) warning.

I cannot imagine that something like "did poorly in last interview, grill him again!" will be part of your immigration record. It's not like a vocabulary quiz in school which you barely passed so that the teacher will ask more thoroughly next time around.

A similar thing happened to me - two years ago on my first trip to the US with an ESTA I had to go to secondary inspection, answer questions, fill in forms etc. The next time I was back after that was a bit nerve-wracking, but I've since visited more than 10 times over two years and had zero problems! (although I was able to get global entry after the first few so that probably made things easier)

CBP does not, following an entry interview, shrug and say “I just dunno, but I guess we’ll let you in and see what happens”. The fact that they let you in means that whatever concerns they initially had were resolved to their satisfaction. Otherwise you would’ve been sent home. You are not a Person Of Interest. There is no cloud of suspicion over you.
The fact that you kept your nose clean and left on time on your previous entry is a huge point in your favor for future interviews. First-timers are a much greater overstay risk than repeat visitors. There’s no way to be certain of what’ll happen next time, but I would be greatly surprised if your next interview involved remotely the same level of scrutiny as the first one given how well things turned out.

There are two things in your story that are entirely allowed but will likely raise flags with some individual officers at least, if not some sort of (secret) official screening criteria.  These are your status as a sole trader and your "mid-eastern ethnicity and legal name."  The trip to Turkey could also be a contributing factor, but is of course, by itself, entirely unproblematic.  (I, a non-middle-eastern white guy with a US passport, was once asked "what were you doing in Turkey?" when driving into the US from Canada.)
As Sneftel says, the fact that they let you in means that they determined that you would not break the rules or be a threat, and your subsequent timely departure from the US only reinforces that.  But given your "risk factors" you should probably be prepared for the possibility of additional scrutiny on subsequent visits.  Officers are more likely to suspect a sole trader or freelancer of planning to work illegally in the US, for example.  The additional scrutiny is very likely to lead to the same outcome on subsequent visits as it did on the first: the officers will resolve any suspicion to their satisfaction and admit you.
The Department of Homeland Security does have a "redress" program for people who are repeatedly subjected to delays at the border (among other difficulties), but it would seem that you haven't yet reached the point where applying for this program makes sense.  If it does get to that point, more information is available on the Department of Homeland Security's website: DHS Traveler Redress Inquiry Program (DHS TRIP).

Couldn’t the repeat entries at more or less regular interval increase the suspicion of illegal work at some point?

@DidierL I suppose that is possible, but it would not likely increase it so much as to cause CBP to refuse admission.  There are many people who visit the US regularly for pleasure, too, and any suspicion that these visits are for employment should be relatively easy to dispel.

@DidierL more likely if the visits were long ones, not a few weeks twice a year. Do that on an ESTA every 2-3 months and you may raise some eyebrows (maybe a salesperson doing business in the US on a tourist visa for example) but heck, if my employer wants me to deal with our US office for 2 weeks a business visa is cheaper than a day in a hotel, and more likely they'll arrange for the entire thing to be done remote to save on travel cost.

@jwenting ESTA has the same allowed activities as B-1/B-2 so business activities are allowed, not just tourism.

@jcaron indeed, and the travel pattern in the question seems normal for a business visitor.  I didn't go into that in the discussion because here the visitor isn't a business visitor, so there's no point in getting sidelined by the question of the blurry lines between permissible business visits and impermissible working.  If CPB suspects working, the response won't depend on this distinction; instead, it will be to show evidence of the social nature of the visit (although being able to show that one's income comes exclusively from non-US sources could help in both cases).

@jcaron however, both with the visa waiver program and with a B-1/B-2 visa, it's necessary to disclose the business purpose of the visit at the admission interview and be admitted in the appropriate status -- WB for the VWP or B-1 with a visa.

@DidierL Two normal-tourist-length visits within about a year seems not particularly suspicious. If anything, I suspect the first visit is a positive since OP left again without issues.
